# Why does .NET System.IO.File use Create/Open instead of a constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

System.IO.File doesn't have a constructor.  Create/Open static methods are used instead.

Why isn't File created or opened with a constructor?

Does calling a constructor some how imply that the code calling the constructor "owns" the object and that isn't the case with something like a file where the object just wraps a handle to a file owned by the file system?  Is this some OOP convention, a .NET/C# convention, or is this just purely arbitrary?

Comment: In C++, std::fstream can be constructed with flags to dictate opening an existing file or creating a new file.  But it also allows empty construction followed by a call to open with flags controlling whether a new file is created or an existing file is opened.  Perhaps the C# way of doing things is a more modern version of OOP.

Comment: I think *Create* and *Open* are associated with operations, not objects.  You *open* a file, you don't *create* an "open".  Since these operations are not associated with an instance, they're made static.

Comment: Sure, you could create a File object, and somehow specify if you want to open it or create it or what.  This would lead to all sorts of convoluted constructors.  A factory pattern is *exactly* what you want here.  The design is correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The File class was a late addition to the .NET Framework version 1.0.  Added after Microsoft conducted a usability study.  They invited programmers that never used .NET before and asked them to write code that used the FileStream and StreamWriter classes.  The ones that have a constructor.  The success rate was *zero*.

So they came up with File, it has a bunch of static helper methods that create/open files.  Think of them as factory methods.  And no, you don't create a File.  You use it.  Check your favorite C# programming language book about *static class*.

Answer (score 9):

[`File.Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03(v=vs.110).aspx) and `Open` don't actually instantiate a `File`, they return a new `FileStream` for accessing the data within the file on disk.

They are essentially factory methods for the [FileStream Constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx), which *are* handled as constructors for `FileStream` instances.

Answer (score 1):

`File` is just helper class that instantiates other classes for you.  A "file" itself is an object on the file system, not in .NET.  So you have streams, readers, `FileInfo`, etc that all represent different aspects of interaction with files.  `File` class in .NET is just a gateway to all these different classes.

Comment: Is there an OOP term for this or is this an example of some pattern or something?  I sort of get what you are saying, but I find it hard to articulate and distiguish what kinds of classes represent objects that are not in .NET.  For example, following the same line of thought should a database have create/open instead of a constructor?  What about classes representing things that are stored in that database?

Comment: Given that you can construct a FileStream instance, I start to doubt your reasoning about objects "not in .NET".  Instead, I think it probably makes sense for any object to be considered as being in .NET, or else why would it be an object at all?

Comment: @JDiMatteo The `File` class is an example of the facade pattern. There are methods to simplify common operations like opening, copying, moving, and writing text to files. One might call some of the methods factory methods as well since they create `FileStream` objects for client code.